# CSV read specific row in python

Tags: python, selenium, csv

I am a beginner in automation field.I have a CSV file with 50 rows each row contains urls.I'm trying to capture only specific rows.

csv file
1.www.google.com
2.www.facebook.com

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path=(.......notepad++\chromedriver.exe')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
with open('list.csv') as fb:
    reader=csv.reader(fb)
    rows=[r for r in reader]
driver.get(rows[1])
driver.quit()
```

error:
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string

Answer (score 1):

`rows[1]` is going to be a row, presumably corresponding to the second row of your CSV file.

I imagine your error message is coming from the call to `driver.get`, which is telling you it wants a string, not a row of strings.  So I'd try grabbing whichever field in the row has the URL.  I'm not sure how you're describing your CSV, but if it look like this:

```
1, google.com
2, facebook.com
```

then it should probably look something like this:

```
driver.get(rows[1][1])
```

Or, more readably,

```
number, url = rows[1]
driver.get(url)
```